# how to change "Line In" microphone from mono to stero

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am working on a project which uses alsa line in and line out, I want to split left and right line in/out to be able to have two independent mono audio input & output.
I did this with this configuration in "asoundrc" file:

```
pcm.dsnoop0 {
    type dsnoop     # Direct snoop
    ipc_key 321400     # unique IPC key
    ipc_key_add_uid true    # add current uid to unique IPC key
    slave{
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        #format S32_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings{
        0 0
    }
}
pcm.dmix0 {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 321410  # any unique value
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave{
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        #format S16_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
    }
}

pcm.duplex0 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm dmix0
    capture.pcm dsnoop0

}
pcm.plug0 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex0"
}

pcm.dsnoop1 {
    type dsnoop     # Direct snoop
    ipc_key 321420     # unique IPC key
    ipc_key_add_uid true    # add current uid to unique IPC key
    slave{
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        #format S32_LE
        rate 16000
        channels 2
        period_time 0
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings {
        1 1
    }

}
pcm.dmix1 {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 321430  # any unique value
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave{
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        #format S16_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings{
    1 1
    }
}

pcm.duplex1 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm dmix1
    capture.pcm dsnoop1

}
pcm.plug1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex1"
}
```

audio output works fine, but my ubuntu determines "Line in" as mono, how can I change that to be as stereo "Line in"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was in my ipc_key:

```
pcm.dev0{
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0

}
ctl.dev0{
    type hw
    card 0
}

pcm.dmix0 {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 321400  # any unique value
    ipc_key_add_uid 1    # add current uid to unique IPC key
    ipc_perm 0666
    slave{
        pcm dev0
        format S16_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
    }
}
pcm.dmix1 {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 321400  # any unique value
    ipc_key_add_uid 1    # add current uid to unique IPC key
    ipc_perm 0666
    slave{
        pcm dev0
        format S16_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings {
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.dsnoop0 {
    type dsnoop     # Direct snoop
    ipc_key 321400     # unique IPC key
    ipc_perm 0666
    slave{
        pcm dev0
        format S16_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings.0 0
}

pcm.dsnoop1 {
    type dsnoop     # Direct snoop
    ipc_key 321400     # unique IPC key

    ipc_perm 0666
    slave{
        pcm dev0
        format S16_LE
        rate 16000
        period_time 0
        channels 2
        period_size 320  # must be power of 2
        buffer_size 10240  # ditto
    }
    bindings.0 1
}

pcm.duplex0 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm dmix0
    capture.pcm dsnoop0
    #bindings.0 0

}

pcm.duplex1 {
    type asym
    playback.pcm dmix1
    capture.pcm dsnoop1

}

pcm.plug0 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex0"
}

pcm.plug1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex1"
}
```